# Video.js on windows 8, ie10. Playhead moves but video doesn't play

Tags: javascript, windows-8, internet-explorer-10, video.js

I'm using the latest video.js files from their server. And using basically the same markup as their example,  however on ie10 (windows 8 only)  the playhead moves but I get no feedback from the video.

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video.js"></script>
```

I am using the standard video tag implementation from their homepage example including the data-setup="{}"

```
<video id="home_hero_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="360" poster="img/poster.jpg" data-setup="{}">
 <source src="http://mysite/myvid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="http://mysite/myvid.webm" type="video/webm">
 <source src="http://mysite/myvid.ogv" type="video/ogv">
</video>
```

Has anyone come across this issue?
Is there a fix?
Is it a video.js bug that hasn't been discovered yet or a user(me)  error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I noticed that too - on IE9.
Player.currentTime fails in IE if the time being set is outside of the buffered zone.
It does not fail in FF, Chrome.

Try setting the preload to "auto", this should fix the problem of seeking forward.
Unfortunately it does not solve the problem of seeking backwards. You can reproduce it in the test player on http://www.videojs.com/  in IE9

Traced it to the exception thrown in this method of the videojs source

```
vjs.Html5.prototype.setCurrentTime = function(seconds){
  try {
    this.el_.currentTime = seconds;
  } catch(e) {
    vjs.log(e, 'Video is not ready. (Video.js)');
    // this.warning(VideoJS.warnings.videoNotReady);
  }
};
```

It looks to me that the exception is only thrown by the IE's implementation of the video element and only when time being set is outside of the buffered zone.

I'm also struggling with this issue. Would appreciate any help.